# Skype plugin for sending rich formatted text

Tags: chat, skype, rtf

When I paste Rich Text Format or HTML text in Linc it will send as it is. Skype instead will loose the formatting.

Is there any plugin that prevents the lost of formatting and allows skype to send RTF messages?

Comment: It implies that the receiver install the same plugin isn't it?

Comment: I don't know.. if it's the only possibility then yes..